# How do I split a file into several files by a multi-character delimiter?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, awk

On Unix, without adding anything to the OS (i.e. only using *grep*, *awk*, *sed*, *cut*, etc.), how can I split the following input into several files (e.g. "_temp1.txt", "_temp2.txt", etc.) starting with each "codeView" line?
Note, it is likely that the line begins with several spaces.

What if the input is coming from an API instead of an existing file?

```
. . .
"events" : [ {
"id" : "123456",
"important" : true,
"codeView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "NORMAL_CODE",
      "value" : "str = wrapper.getParameter("
    }, {
      "type" : "NORMAL_CODE",
      "value" : ")"
    } ],
    "text" : "str = wrapper.getParameter(&quot;motif&quot;)"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
"probableStartLocationView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:12"
    } ],
    "text" : "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:92"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
"dataView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "TAINT_VALUE",
      "value" : "CP"
    } ],
    "text" : "{{#taint}}CP{{/taint}}"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
"collapsedEvents" : [ ],
"dupes" : 0
}, {
"id" : "28861,28862",
"important" : false,
"type" : "P2O",
"description" : "String Operations Occurred",
"extraDetails" : null,
          "codeView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "TEXT",
      "value" : "Over the following lines of code, blah blah."
    } ],
    "text" : "Over the following lines of code, blah blah."
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
"probableStartLocationView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "remplaceString() @ O_UtilCaractere.java:234"
    } ],
    "text" : "remplaceString() @ O_UtilCaractere.java:234"
  }, {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "replaceString() @ O_UtilCaractere.java:333"
    } ],
    "text" : "replaceString() @ O_UtilCaractere.java:333"
  }, {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "creerIncidentPaie() @ Incidents.java:444"
    } ],
    "text" : "creerIncidentPaie() @ Incidents.java:219"
  }, {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "repliquerAbsenceIncident() @ Incidents.java:876"
    } ],
    "text" : "repliquerAbsenceIncident() @ IncidentsPaieMgr.java:882"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
"dataView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "TEXT",
      "value" : "insert into TGE_INCIDENT...4&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;YYYYMMDD&amp;apos;), &amp;apos;A&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;"
    }, {
      "type" : "TAINT_VALUE",
      "value" : "CP"
    }, {
      "type" : "TEXT",
      "value" : "&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;&amp;apos;, null, &amp;apos;T&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;ADPTVT&amp;apos;, to_date(&amp;apos;2013012214..."
    } ],
    "text" : "insert into TGE_INCIDENT...4&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;YYYYMMDD&amp;apos;), &amp;apos;A&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;{{#taint}}CP{{/taint}}&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;&amp;apos;, null, &amp;apos;T&amp;apos;, &amp;apos;ADPTVT&amp;apos;, to_date(&amp;apos;2017062214..."
  } ],
  "nested" : false
}
. . .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work robustly in any awk:

```
awk '/"codeView"/{close(out); out="_temp" ++c ".txt"} out!=""{print > out}' file
```

Comment: You're missing an `'` after the last `}`. You said "This will work robustly in any awk:", well it doesn't for me in macOS BSD awk or GNU Awk 4.1.3.

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting in GNU Awk, under both macOS and Linux Mint: `gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file FNR=1) fatal: expression for '>' redirection has null string value`

Comment: Then your file must not start with a "codeView" line. Where do you want the pre-codeView lines to be printed to? Or do you want them to just be dropped? I tweaked the script to drop them for now. btw the script is portable to ALL awks - no-one needs to go testing it on multiple platforms with multiple awks, it will work exactly the same in all awks no matter where you execute it.

Comment: I copied directly from the OP and karakfa's answer works once the  missing `'` after the last `}` in his answer is placed.

Comment: @user3439894 right, it will work in GNU awk and it will also work in some other awks as long as the input file doesn't contain many `codeView` lines. See the comment I left under his answer explaining that.

Comment: Okay, the last edit you made fixed it, it now works in BSD Awk and GNU Awk. BTW I only mentioned karakfa's answer cause it worked when yours didn't however I saw your comment to his answer and up voted the comment as I agree with it and your way is better, which is why I uprooted your edited answer and not his.

Comment: Again, there is nothing about the script that is unique to any awk, it will behave the same in all awks so no need to keep testing it on multiple platforms. btw you said karakfas answer worked but did you look at the output it produced given the same input you tested mine against? The OP didn't say she expected a file named just `_temp.txt` output, she wants `_temp1.txt`, `_temp2,txt`, etc. so I wouldn't consider that as working either in that case and IMHO producing an error message given unexpected input is better than quietly accepting it and producing unexpected output.

Comment: Yes I looked, the _temp.txt file contained the content up till the first `"codeView"` and can be ignored, but I agree with your assessment. The context of my worked statement was to show it process the `file` and didn't error out as yours did until the edit you made. I test in both environments because I work in both. Anyway, thanks I always learn lots from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
csplit -f _temp -b %d.tmp file '/codeView/' '{*}'
```

Or, if the data comes from some other program:

```
my_api | csplit -f _temp -b %d.tmp - '/codeView/' '{*}'
```

#### How it works

- `-f _temp -b %d.tmp`

  These two options sets the names of the split files to format that you want.
- `file`

  Replace this with the name of your input file.  Use `-` if input is to come from stdin.
- `/codeView/`

  This is the regex that you want to split on.
- `'{*}'`

  This tells csplit not to stop at the first match but to keep splitting.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/"codeView"/{c++} {print > ("_temp" (c+0) ".txt")}' file
```

the header up to the first match will be in the 0th temp file.  If there is a chance that the key may appear in the content perhaps change pattern match to literal match `$1=="\"codeView\""`

you can pipe in the data to the `awk` script instead of reading from a file as well.

If there are too many files opened, you may want to close them before it errs out.

Comment: You should mention that not parenthesisizng the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior per POSIX so that'll only do what you want in some awks and also if your file is large you'll get a "too many open files" error from some awks due to not closing the output files as you go. It will work fine in GNU awk so you could just say it's gawk-only.